# How to apply a windows domain network in multiple locations

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, domain-controller

I would like to implement a Windows Domain Network, corp.mydomain.com.

The domain network will consist of 3 LANs (in small offices/residences) that will use Comcast or AT&T as their internet provider.

I would prefer to have at least 2 domain controllers at each location.

From what I understand, it would be costly to do a Wide Area Network. If I use Virtual Private Networking, can it be set up on the domain controllers of the 2 remote locations? I want to make the 3 LANs exist on the domain without user execution.

Are there any alternatives other than VPN or WAN? I have done some research but haven't found any detailed documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Hire. A. Consultant. (The answer BTW is to run site-to-site VPNs on your routers, but seriously, if you have the funds for 6 DCs, multiple offices etc, then hire someone and get it done right)

Comment: @ChrisS or BlueCompute: Thank you! Please create an answer to get credit.

Answer (score 0):

In small offices or satellite locations, VPN is the most common way to do this. Typically each location's router would be capable of running the VPN. Even lower end Cisco (ASA5505) or Juniper (SSG5) routers do VPNs easily.

MPLS or other virtual circuits are more common in larger offices. These sorts of solutions have a higher base price, but allow greater flexibility and performance. Basically start with VPN and if that isn't meeting your demands then call up the local ISPs and see what they offer.